# Heroku doesn't read my requirements.txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord, discord.py

My team and I are currently developing a Discord bot with Python. We're temporarily using Heroku to host the bot, in the future, this may change but for now, Heroku it is.

Heroku straight up doesn't read our requirements.txt file. Is it formatted incorrectly, or anything like that? It used to work but one of my team members added a new requirement and it does not work anymore. Here's what the file contains:

```
discord.py==1.3.3
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
youtube_dl==2020.5.29
aiohttp==3.6.2
ffmpeg==1.4
praw==7.0.0
pycorona==0.5.9
pafy==0.5.5
```

Here's what the Procfile contains just in case it's useful:

```
worker: python MASTERBOT.py
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with our file and what we can do to fix it? I'll provide more information if needed.

Edit: I would like to note that the bot is 100% functional when run locally on our computers.

Comment: worker? it should be `web` as it requires connectivity (workers are for background tasks)

Comment: is that it? because that did not help out

Comment: @BeppeC We tried that and it kept crashing. This part of the log intrigued me: `2020-07-02T19:34:13.340633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Comment: If you a web dyno you need to set the port to $PORT (not hardcoded but using the Heroku env variable). Now to be clear I dont have experience with Discord (it might work differently) but in theory you need to use a Web dyno when the BOT must receive web requests

Comment: @BeppeC As I envisioned, that did not work. I think discord.py works differently because up until now, using worker did the trick. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Deleting the requirements.txt and create another one and include all
  modules name and in the `"cmd"` type `"$git add ."` and commit then push it. which will push all updated files n folder in the current dir.
- Or if you met with a procfile error do

> ```
>  $git add Procfile 
>  $git commit -m "updating procfile"  
>  $git push heroku master
> ```

if you met with dyno problems do

$heroku ps

else try to restart

$heroku restart

Answer (score 0):

Probably `heroku/python` buildpack missed. Just run
`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python` to add and rebuild your app.